# At which consulate in the US should I apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, f1-visas, consulates

I live in the US on an F-1 student visa, and I go to grad school in Philadelphia, Pennsylvania. My I-20 thus mentions Pennsylvania as my state of residence. However, I have moved to Illinois with my wife earlier this year and work remotely (traveling to Philly once a month or so and staying in hotels).

When I apply for a Schengen visa, should I be applying at a consulate that serves PA (which is my official residence on my visa status/I-20) or one that serves IL (where I have all my address proofs of)?

Answer (score 1):

You actually live in Illinois, so you should apply to the consulate serving Illinois.

You also should update your I-20, if appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot update my I-20 till I graduate because that is tied to my university (which is in PA).

Comment: @wrahool You can't even change your address with the university?

Comment: I can and I have, but the I-20 has my university's address; not my address. Visa officials interpret that to mean that I also reside in that or a neighboring region.